# Progress bar for a web browser control

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, webbrowser-control

How can I put, and use, a progress bar for my web browser control, in a windows application project, using the c# language?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [WebBrowser.ProgressChanged](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged) event.

Answer (score 2):

The `WebBrowser` control has a `ProgressChanged` event:

You need to attach an event handler to the `ProgressChanged` event:

```
WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged += WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged;
```

This is shorthand for:

```
WebBrowser1.ProgressChanged += new WebBrowserProgressChangedEventHandler(WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged);
```

The compiler will infer the handler and add that at compile time.

Next, implement the handler:

```
private void WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.CurrentProgress;
}
```

The `WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs` type supports a `CurrentProgress` property which reflects the current state of the browser control's progress.

Comment: where do you define "CurrentProgress"?
what does this mean?
what does first line of your code before function do?

Comment: Thank you Mr.Abbott
could you tell me how i can merge MenuItems of parent and child with  same name ??????????

Comment: You'll have to explain that a bit more, possibly raise it as a new SO question.

Comment: i raised but i dont receive any answer
i explain to you with example : 
i have 2 form,in one of them ISmdicontainer is true and it is parentform,this form have menu strip that is named file with 2 items: open and new.
other form will open in the form above and will be childform, this form have menu strip that is named file too.this file menu have 2 items : save and exit.
when i open second form in first form, i have one menu strip with to file in it.I want to have one file whit 4 items :open,new,save,exit

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebBrowser.ProgressChanged` Event, but to report the progress use the code below:

```
private void WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, 
                                         WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Maximum = (int) e.MaximumProgress;
    if (e.CurrentProgress > 0)
       progressBar.Value = (int) e.CurrentProgress;
}
```