# How to load web page in Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, load, html

I just want to load a web page, I don't want to open it.

I want to show the page load process in a progressbar.

When page load completes, I want to show a message: "page load completed".

I used this code but it opens the browser:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");

Answer (score 5):

You can use web browser control on your form.

See below samples on:

[Web Browser in C# Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60179/Web-Browser-in-C)

[WebBrowser.ProgressChanged Event MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged)

[Progress bar for a web browser control in windows application project using c# SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386135/progress-bar-for-a-web-browser-control-in-windows-application-project-using-c-sh)

[C# Winforms: Using a progress bar with Web Browser Control Wordpress](http://hashfactor.wordpress.com/2009/03/31/c-winforms-using-a-progress-bar-with-web-browser-control/)

Comment: Please give me code how to load webpage & show page-load process in progressbar ?

Comment: check the list of sites above..best regards

Comment: @BizApps Web browser control doesnt support css grid, what might be alternative to that?