# Assign ProgressBar to WebBrowser Page Loading

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, webbrowser-control

I'm using the WebBrowser control to browse to different pages (by clicking buttons on the Form itself, which navigate the WebBrowser control to the different pages). When it's loading the page, I want a ProgressBar to animate. Whether or not it actually indicates the progress is not a huge deal - I could just use the Marquee style to animate it while loading.

The question is: How do I make the ProgressBar animate in this fashion when the page is loading, and stop when the page is finished loading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [WebBrowser.ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.progresschanged) event. The MSDN page says it's pretty "similar to the one in Internet Explorer".

Code snippet straight from there:

```
private void WebBrowser1_ProgressChanged(Object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e) {

    System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "CurrentProgress", e.CurrentProgress );
    messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
    messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "MaximumProgress", e.MaximumProgress );
    messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "ProgressChanged Event" );
}
```

[`e.CurrentProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.currentprogress) would indicate how many bytes have been downloaded so far, [`e.MaximumProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserprogresschangedeventargs.maximumprogress) would indicate how many bytes there are to download. It's pretty easy to get a percentage straight from that so... there you go!

I won't walk you through how to make a progress bar (there's TONS of implementations out there for it) but this should get you going.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Somewhat. I've looked at several progress bar implementations and most say to assign e.CurrentProgress to progressBar.Value. However, since it is a long, I have to cast it as an int (something I don't see the examples doing), and then I get an error (as the progress turns up as -1...casting error, I'm guessing). See here for the example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386135/progress-bar-for-a-web-browser-control-in-windows-application-project-using-c-sh

Comment: @rar I don't think that's quite right, you need to set `progressBar.Maxiumum` as `e.MaximumProgress`, otherwise the current value of the progress bar has no reference.

Comment: Doing so also gives me the error stating that it needs to be cast as an int. I'll try this now that I have the maximum set... EDIT: Nope, still get -1 as my `e.CurrentProgress`